# MIPS: Finding the MIN value of three ints. Getting wrong output. Why?

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

```
.data
prompt: .asciiz "Enter in 3 integers, one per line, last one being a negative number: "
sum:    .asciiz "The sum is: "
min:    .asciiz "The minimum is: "
max:    .asciiz "The maximum is: "
mean:   .asciiz "The mean is: "
variance:   .asciiz "The variance is: "
newline:    .asciiz "\n"
count:    .word 3
array:    .space 12
.text
main:
    #prints prompt msg
    li    $v0, 4
    la    $a0, prompt
    syscall

    #takes first integer from user and stores into $t1
    li    $v0, 5
    syscall
    move     $t1, $v0


    #takes second integer from user and stores into $t2
    li    $v0, 5
    syscall
    move     $t2, $v0


    #takes third integer from user and stores into $t3
    li    $v0, 5
    syscall
    move    $t3, $v0


    #min/max utilizing array
    la    $t0, array        #initializing array at a[0]
    li    $t4, 0            #min
    li    $t5, 0            #max
    li    $t6, 0            #i
    li    $t7, 0
    sw    $t1, 4($t0)        #user first input stored in a[1]
    sw    $t2, 8($t0)        #user second input stored in a[2]
    sw    $t3, 12($t0)        #user third input stored in a[3]


blt $t1, $t2, Else
ble $t1, $t3, Else2
j T1P

Else:
    blt $t2, $t3, Else2
    j T2P

Else2:
    blt $t3, $t2, T3P

T1P:
    move $a0, $t1
    li   $v0, 1
    syscall

T2P:
    move $a0, $t2
    li   $v0, 1
    syscall

T3P:
    move $a0, $t3
    li   $v0, 1
    syscall
```

**Ok,what I am trying to do is find the min value out of three user inputted integers.**

**The program will run and allow the user to input their three integers.**

**What is happening is that instead of printing out the min value, all three values are printing out.**

```
blt $t1, $t2, Else
    ble $t1, $t3, Else2
    j T1P

    Else:
        blt $t2, $t3, Else2
        j T2P

    Else2:
        blt $t3, $t2, T3P

    T1P:
        move $a0, $t1
        li   $v0, 1
        syscall

    T2P:
        move $a0, $t2
        li   $v0, 1
        syscall

    T3P:
        move $a0, $t3
        li   $v0, 1
        syscall
```

**This is the section of code that is suppose to check which value is the smallest, it isn't.**

**I don't understand why all three integers are printing out. I thought that my error checks would prevent all three integers from being printed. I am running this program in QTSPIM.**

**Example: User punches in 4 , 3 , and 2 as their three ints. Console is showing 4, 3,and 2, instead of just printing the smallest int.**

Comment: There's nothing that prevents the code after `T2P` and `T3P` to be executed if you jumped to `T1P`. A label is just a name that you can use to conveniently refer to a specific location in your program; it's not some kind of magic barrier. Use a branching instruction whenever you want to change the execution flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to exit out of the conditional execution sections once they execute.  In other words:

```
    blt $t1, $t2, Else
    ble $t1, $t3, Else2
    j T1P

Else:
    blt $t2, $t3, Else2
    j T2P

Else2:
    blt $t3, $t2, T3P

T1P:
    move $a0, $t1
    li   $v0, 1
    syscall
    j END

T2P:
    move $a0, $t2
    li   $v0, 1
    syscall
    j END

T3P:
    move $a0, $t3
    li   $v0, 1
    syscall

END:
```